# How to extract relations between classes using java files instead of class files?

Tags: java, bcel

I'm trying to modify the code below to make it work on java files instead of class files. But I have no idea what are some possible ways to do that. So basically I have to get rid of BCEL ClassParser and extract relations directly from Java files? Any leads?

```
Function<ClassParser, ClassVisitor> getClassVisitor =
                (ClassParser cp) -> {
                    try {
                        return new ClassVisitor(cp.parse());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                    }
                };
try (JarFile jar = new JarFile(f)) {
                    Stream<JarEntry> entries = enumerationAsStream(jar.entries());
               
                    String methodCalls = entries.
                            flatMap(e -> {
                                if (e.isDirectory() || !e.getName().endsWith(".class"))
                                    return (new ArrayList<String>()).stream();

                                ClassParser cp = new ClassParser(arg, e.getName());
                                System.out.println("Name:"+e.getName());
                                
                                return getClassVisitor.apply(cp).start().methodCalls().stream();
                            }).
                            map(s -> s + "\n").
                            reduce(new StringBuilder(),
                                    StringBuilder::append,
                                    StringBuilder::append).toString();
```

Comment: Your "any leads?" is actually a request for us to find and/or recommend a Java parser library for you.  That's off-topic.  Just google for "java parser library" and scan through the hits.

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries that allow you to parse .java files :

QDOX :
https://github.com/paul-hammant/qdox

JavaParser : https://javaparser.org/

Comment: Thank you for answering @Oussama ZAGHDOUD. Sorry for the vague question. Let me try to clarify a bit more. I want to know is if I can parse java files (instead of class files) and still use the same code. In other words, can I create a java class object using BCEL while using java files instead of class files. Thanks again.

Comment: try to see this example , it use BCEL with .java files : https://www.javatips.net/api/Link-Time-Optimizer-master/src/main/java/lto/libinfo/ListAnnotations.java